# Encountering an infinite loop depending on compiler and declarations

Tags: c, windows, mingw

In this program there is a line where I create a variable called 
"crazy_integer".

If I do not create this variable, MinGW creates an infinite loop!
I do not seem to have this problem with any other compiler.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

To recreate: Download the latest version of CodeBlocks with MingW, create
a new console project, and try running this program.

Then, try removing the line of code where I create "crazy_integer" 
and run the program again. The result should be an infinite loop.

```
// In this program there is a line where I create a variable called 
// "crazy_integer". 
//
// If I do not create this variable, CodeBlocks creates an infinite loop!
// I do not seem to have this problem with any other compiler.
//
// Can anyone tell me what is going on here? 
//
// To recreate: Download the latest version of CodeBlocks with MingW, create
// a new console project, and try running this program.
//
// Then, try removing the line of code where I create "crazy_integer" 
// and run the program again. The result should be an infinite loop.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int find_winning_move(char *, char, int);
int display_board(char *);
int is_winning_position(char *, char);
void show_win_details(int, char);

int main(void) {
    int retval = 0;
    char raw_data[]         = "X  X XO  ";
    char player = 'X';

    printf("We are examining this board:  \n");
    display_board(raw_data);

    find_winning_move(raw_data, player, 1);

    return 0;
}

int find_winning_move(char *raw_data, char player, int depth) {

    char test_position[9];
    int crazy_integer=0;    // Adding this line will fix an infinite loop
    int i, win_result;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (raw_data[i] == ' ') {
            strcpy(test_position, raw_data);
            test_position[i] = player;
            win_result = is_winning_position(test_position, player);
            printf("The result of playing %c at position %d is: %d  \n",
                player, i, win_result);

            display_board(test_position);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int display_board(char *raw_data) {
    char display_model[]     = "[ ][ ][ ]\n[ ][ ][ ]\n[ ][ ][ ]\n";

    int i, j, k; k=0;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 7; j+=3) {
            display_model[ (i * 10) + j ] = raw_data[k++];
        }
    }

    printf("%s ", display_model);
}

int is_winning_position(char *raw_data, char player) {

    int i;

    // Test for horizontal win
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i+=3) {
        if (raw_data[i] == player
            && raw_data[i+1] == player
            && raw_data[i+2] == player)
        {
            return 10 + i;
        }
    }

    // Test for vertical win
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (raw_data[i] == player
            && raw_data[i+3] == player
            && raw_data[i+6] == player)
        {
             return 20 + i;
        }
    }

    // Test for diagonal win
    if (raw_data[4] == player) {
        if (raw_data[0] == player && raw_data[8] == player) {
            return 31;
        }
        if (raw_data[2] == player && raw_data[6] == player) {
            return 32;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

void show_win_details(int win_value, char player) {

    switch (win_value) {

        // Horizontal
        case 10 :
            printf("Horizontal win on first row for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;
        case 13 :
            printf("Horizontal win on second row for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;
        case 16 :
            printf("Horizontal win on third row for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;

        // Vertical
        case 20 :
            printf("Vertical win on first column for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;
        case 21 :
            printf("Vertical win on second column for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;
        case 22 :
            printf("Vertical win on third column for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;

        // Diagonal
        case 31 :
            printf("Diagonal win upper left to lower right for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;
        case 32 :
            printf("Diagonal win lower left to upper right for Player: %c  \n",
                player);
        break;

        default: printf("Some error occurred.  \n"); break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable declaration:

```
char test_position[9];
```

Is too short for the `strcpy` into it (`strcpy(test_position, raw_data);`).  The source buffer `raw_data` is 9 characters plus the null terminator.  So it results in a buffer overflow.  Adding that integer variable probably provides extra space on the stack that "fixes" the stack overflow.

Comment: I suspect that moving the declaration of `test_position` *after* the declaration of the two `int`s will also resolve the infinite loop.  You'll still be corrupting the stack, but at least you won't be corrupting your loop counter.

Comment: Yes of course, that makes perfect sense. Question then, why does it work in other compilers? It works fine in Linux when I write: gcc test.c -o test

Comment: @user1547160 Different compilers can lay out the stack variables in different orders, or can use different amounts of padding between them.  As written, your code most certainly doesn't "work" in Linux.  You simply haven't seen a catastrophic failure yet ("yet" being the operative word).  The stack is still being corrupted, so the danger is still there.

Comment: @user1547160:  The stack layout is compiler dependent.  A buffer overflow results in undefined behavior.  As someone mentioned on one answer, it would be perfectly legal for your computer to order a pizza for you when undefined behavior is triggered (and it might even ask for anchovies).